# I got a undefined value in dot then function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, undefined

**This is my full codes**

```
const Login = () => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation()
    const url = location.state?.from || '/';


    const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
    const { register, handleSubmit, reset } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = data => {
        axios.post('https://vast-stream-90795.herokuapp.com/userLogin', data)
            .then(result => {
                const idToken = result.data.accessToken;
                localStorage.setItem('idToken', idToken)
                if (result.status === 200) {
                    fetch(`https://vast-stream-90795.herokuapp.com/users?email=${data.email}`)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            data &&
                                setUser(data)
                            history.push(url)
                            alert('Login Successful')
                            sessionStorage.setItem('email', data.user?.email)
                            reset();
                        })
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    };


    return (
        <Box sx={{ width: { xs: '100%', md: '30%' }, mx: 'auto', py: 4, textAlign: 'center' }}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

                <TextField required label="Email" variant="outlined" type="email" {...register("email")} sx={{ width: '100%' }} />
                <br /><br />
                <TextField required label="Password" variant="outlined" type="password" {...register("password")} sx={{ width: '100%' }} />
                <br /><br />
                <Button type='submit' variant='contained'>Login</Button>
            </form>
            <Typography>
                New to CoreDevs Tuitorial?
                <Link to="/SignUp">Sign Up</Link>
                <p>{user[0]?.name}</p>
            </Typography>

        </Box>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

I want to get the email given from users. But I want it if the backend gives me the status 200. When I tried to fetch the user's data from the backend after getting the status code 200, I have got the value is undefined.

after this line(below), I have got the status as 200 but then I have got the value of email is undefined.

```
if (result.status === 200) {
                    fetch(`https://vast-stream-90795.herokuapp.com/users?email=${data.email}`)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            data &&
                                setUser(data)
                            history.push(url)
                            alert('Login Successful')
                            sessionStorage.setItem('email', data.user?.email)
                            reset();
                        })
                }
            })
```

How can I get the email? Please help me.

Comment: so what is in data? `console.log(data.user)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your endpoint is returning an array of objects, not a single JSON object.

To read data from that output, you would need to define the index of an array element that you would read.
For your example, I guess it would be `data[0].user` if every object returned by that endpoint has the user property set.

This is just a wild guess from the output I'm seeing by hitting the endpoint with a random e-mail.

It would be more clear if you could provide a test email that returns some test data.